# phonegap install error on windows

Tags: cordova

I am getting this error installing phone gap on my windows machine,

```
C:\>npm install -g phonegap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap/-/phonegap-3.5.0-0.20.1.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap/-/phonegap-3.5.0-0.20.1.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qrcode-terminal
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pluralize
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/prompt
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap-build
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-lib
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect-phonegap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/shelljs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qrcode-terminal
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pluralize
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/prompt
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/phonegap-build
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect-phonegap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-lib
npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: cordova-lib@'lorinbeer/cordova-li
b.git#pg.3.5.0'
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget ["0.21.2","0.21.3"]
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd C:\
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! Error: EPERM, open 'C:\npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, open 'C:\npm-debug.log'] errno: 50, code: 'EPERM', pa
th: 'C:\\npm-debug.log' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd C:\
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.28
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! path C:\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno 50
npm ERR! stack Error: EPERM, open 'C:\npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

dont know what to do. please help.

i have tried few things like clearing cache and updating software but nothing worked.
I have installed node.js 10.28 V

Answer (score 6):

Download the older version. I think there was a problem in the new one

```
npm install -g phonegap@3.4
```